# Unexpected return value from visitor method

Tags: babeljs

I'm trying to upgrade from webpack@1 to webpack@4 and babel@6 to babel@7 at the same time.  I'm getting the error below and I can't tell if it's my code or a bug in babel.  I don't see anything special in f.js lines 10-27, but I've copied obfuscated versions of lines 9-28 below as well in case there is.  I've also included the debug output of preset-env, to show the loaded plugins.

```
ERROR in ./c/b/a.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: /home/jayen/cui/c/b/a.js: Unexpected return value from visitor method function (path) {
          return fn.call(state, path, state);
        }
    at NodePath._call (/home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:62:13)
    at NodePath.call (/home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:42:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:99:8)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:112:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:84:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:140:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (/home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:84:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:97:18)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:112:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (/home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:79:17)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:138:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (/home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:84:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:97:18)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:112:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (/home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:79:17)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:138:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (/home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:84:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:97:18)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:112:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:84:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:140:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (/home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:84:17)
    at traverse (/home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:66:12)
    at transformFile (/home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:119:29)
    at runSync (/home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:48:5)
    at runAsync (/home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:35:14)
    at /home/jayen/cui/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:34:34
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
 @ ./c/b/r/f.js 25:10-27
 @ ./c/b/i.js
 @ multi react-hot-loader/patch ./c/b/i
```

```js
const l = t('f', {}, () => {
    const { s } = a.e;
    return o(
        h('woc', [
            hl(
                (s && s.r && s.r.o) || 'c'
            ),
            h('wob', [
                h('woh', [
                    sp,
                    h('wol', [
                        h('wot', `${d('l')}d`),
                        h('p', `${d('t')}`)
                    ])
                ])
            ])
        ]),
        a.e.c
    );
});
```

```
Using targets:
{}

Using modules transform: commonjs

Using plugins:
  transform-template-literals {}
  transform-literals {}
  transform-function-name {}
  transform-arrow-functions {}
  transform-block-scoped-functions {}
  transform-classes {}
  transform-object-super {}
  transform-shorthand-properties {}
  transform-duplicate-keys {}
  transform-computed-properties {}
  transform-for-of {}
  transform-sticky-regex {}
  transform-dotall-regex {}
  transform-unicode-regex {}
  transform-spread {}
  transform-parameters {}
  transform-destructuring {}
  transform-block-scoping {}
  transform-typeof-symbol {}
  transform-new-target {}
  transform-regenerator {}
  transform-exponentiation-operator {}
  transform-async-to-generator {}
  proposal-async-generator-functions {}
  proposal-object-rest-spread {}
  proposal-unicode-property-regex {}
  proposal-json-strings {}
  proposal-optional-catch-binding {}
  transform-named-capturing-groups-regex {}
  transform-member-expression-literals {}
  transform-property-literals {}
  transform-reserved-words {}
  transform-modules-commonjs {}
  proposal-dynamic-import {}

Using polyfills: No polyfills were added, since the `useBuiltIns` option was not set.
```

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the `toString` method helped me find my visitor which was causing problems:

```js
        newFn = function (path) {
          return fn.call(state, path, state);
        };
        newFn.toString = () => fn.toString();
```

https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/10949